# Efficient Drawing with canvas HTML5

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm working on a navigation sytem.My program draws a vector based map onto a canvas element but this operation takes a bit more time.I need to re-draw the map whenever user moves a different location.So i need to draw the map very fast.Is there any method or algorithm to make it?

Comment: Is it a stationary map where points like markers are changed on or is it a map that you can drag and show more of the map? Some more description of exactly what you have would help

Comment: Program will work totally offline.Data is stationary but program will draw a part of the data according to user's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use layers and only redraw parts of the canvas that have actually changed.  Here's a decent introduction to doing it by hand: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-canvashtml5layering/

Alternatively, use a library which has a nice abstraction around these concepts: http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS

Comment: Thanks for advice.now i'm looking into EaselJS.That seems to be work.Have a good day.